# How can I pull user's information from Renren using JS API?

Tags: javascript, rest

I want to build a html form for a Chinese website. And I want connect that form with Renren social media using JS(JavaScript) API. So that user can submit the form via Renren log-in details.

Linked-In provides JS API, which supports the cross-domain policy, using that anyone can pull information from Linked-In at the client machine itself.

Similarly, I just want to know, is it possible to pull information from Renren using JS API which should support Cross-domain policy. I don't want to use any server-side API's.

I have tried the JS-Sdk  from this link  - http://wiki.dev.renren.com/wiki/Js-sdk-1.0
Using that I can only able to authenticate the user with Renren log-in details.
But I don't have a clear idea about how to pull the information from the current logged-in User.

I have tried AJAX calls also, but that is also not working because of cross-domain policy.

Could anyone please help on this?

For reference - Similar Kind of question has been raised in the below Link
[Javascript RenRen API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796645/javascript-renren-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend using a 3rd party such as [Gigya](http://developers.gigya.com/) in order not to have to know every social network API signature. A lot of sites currently use it, such as Nike.com

You can get a free developer key and if you're working for money instead of non-profit, your client should be able to bill for it.

Comment: You are right. Gigya is the prefered one and I ve tried that. But we have some limitations on pulling the user's information here.

http://developers.gigya.com/020_Client_API/010_Socialize/socialize.getRawData
As per the above link if we get the raw data directly from renren, it will be helpful for me.
But currently gigya is not supporting this API for Renren.